# A conta matematica ta dando errado?? C#

Tags: c#

Ola estou muito confuso agora eu peguei a formula de pegar a distancia entre 2 pontos e apliquei na minha aplicação mas esta dando resultado diferente da calculadora
[image: Imagem Explicando o Problema]

codigo em texto:

```
        public static double GetDist(Point A, Point B)
        {
            double X, Y;

            X = (B.X - A.X) ^ 2;
            Y = (B.Y - A.Y) ^ 2;

            Debug.WriteLine($"X:{A.X},Y:{A.Y}");
            Debug.WriteLine($"X:{B.X},Y:{B.Y}");
            Debug.WriteLine($"Result:{X+Y}");
            return Math.Sqrt(X+Y);
        }
```

Entrada: A = {126, 101}, B = {150, 60}.

Codigo Debug Result da: **-17**

sendo que na calc da **2257**
na Conta: **(150-126)^2 + (60-101)^2**

.

.

**Porfavor Ignore** o math.Sqrt porfavor.

Comment: Desculpa si for um Erro bobo mas e que eu to faz tipo 7 horas nesse Erro.

Comment: Tenta usar Math.Pow((B.X - A.X), 2) para os valores de x e y.

Comment: Em *C#* o operador `^` não é potenciação, é conectivo lógico para o [ou exclusivo bit a bit](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/)

Comment: Bernardo Lopes e Augusto Vasquel Obrigado. Um Completou o outro na explicação.

Comment: Use Math.Pow(base, expoente) ou simplesmente: deltax*deltax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,
Se você tem intenção de fazer uma curva cartesiana, deveria fazer um **for** com um range englobando esse código para criar uma curva.

```
public static List<double> GetDist(Point A, Point B){
    List<double> result = new List<double>();
    for (int i = -5; i < 6; i++){
        double X = i, Y = i;

        X = (B.X - A.X) ^ 2;
        Y = (B.Y - A.Y) ^ 2;

        Debug.WriteLine($ "X:{A.X},Y:{A.Y}");
        Debug.WriteLine($ "X:{B.X},Y:{B.Y}");
        Debug.WriteLine($ "Result:{X+Y}");
        result.add(Math.Sqrt(X + Y));
    }
    return result;
}
```